# Flowchart using TiKz - connecting arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

Here is flowchart drawn using TiKz. I'm trying to connect the arrows in a clean way. For instance, I want to connect `box3.west` to `retF.south` and `box2.east` to `retT.south`. I would like to have the arrow end at the midpoint of `retF.south` and `retT.south`. Is there a general way to do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset
{
        process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, text width=2cm, draw},
        arrow/.style={thick, ->, >=stealth},
        decision/.style ={diamond, draw=black, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
    \node (p0) [] {foo(K)};
    \node (p1) [process, below of=p0, text width=4cm] {box1};
    \node (p2) [process, below of=p1, yshift=-1.5cm, text width=4.5cm] {box2};
    \node (p3) [decision, below of=p2, yshift=-1.5cm, text width=2cm] {box3};
    \node (retT) [process, right of=p1, xshift=4cm, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {retT};
    \node (retF) [process, left of=p2, xshift=-5cm, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {retF};


    \draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=west] {need more steps} (p2);
    \draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=south] {no more steps} (retT);
    \draw [arrow] (p2.east) -- ++(1.5,0) node[anchor=north,pos=1] {K = X}   |- (retT.west);
    \draw [arrow] (p2.west) -- node[anchor=north,pos=0.5] {K $<$ X}  (retF.east);
    \draw [arrow] (p2) -- node[anchor=east] {K $>$ X} (p3);
    \draw [arrow] (p3.west) --+(-4.2,0)  node[anchor=north]{No} |- (retF.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{connect box3.west to retF.south}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do `\draw [arrow] (p3.west) -| (retF.south) node[below, pos=0.5] {No};`

Comment: Oh. Now I understand the meaning of `|-`. I was assuming that as a perpendicular line. But it actually means "go perpendicular first and then go straight". Now I can use `-|` for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: @arunmoezhi it actually depends on where `|-` is being used. Here it is an L shaped arrow but in `(A |- B) ` it is a point on a horizontal line through B vertically down/up from A.

Comment: Not really perpendicular, it means "go vertically, then horizontally",  and vice versa for `-|`. Try for example `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) |- (0,0);`.  Unrelated note: The brace pair surrounding the `tikzpicture` environment is unnecessary I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarizing the comments so this question has an actual answer (it was highlighted as unanswered in a recent newsletter).  You want to use the `-|` path operation to draw an L-shaped path.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset
{
        process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, text width=2cm, draw},
        arrow/.style={thick, ->, >=stealth},
        decision/.style ={diamond, draw=black, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
    \node (p0) [] {foo($K$)};
    \node (p1) [process, below of=p0, text width=4cm] {box1};
    \node (p2) [process, below of=p1, yshift=-1.5cm, text width=4.5cm] {box2};
    \node (p3) [decision, below of=p2, yshift=-1.5cm, text width=2cm] {box3};
    \node (retT) [process, right of=p1, xshift=4cm, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {retT};
    \node (retF) [process, left of=p2, xshift=-5cm, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {retF};


    \draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=west] {need more steps} (p2);
    \draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=south] {no more steps} (retT);
    \draw [arrow] (p2.east) -| (retT.south) node[anchor=north,pos=0.5] {$K = X$}  ;
    \draw [arrow] (p2.west) -- node[anchor=north,pos=0.5] {$K < X$}  (retF.east);
    \draw [arrow] (p2) -- node[anchor=east] {$K > X$} (p3);
    \draw [arrow] (p3.west) -| (retF.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

If you want to have multiple L-shaped paths you can do that by adding a coordinate in between.  Adding this line:

```
\draw [arrow] (p3.east) -| ++(1.5cm,1.5cm) node[red] {$\bullet$} -| ([xshift=1cm]p2.south);
```

will draw an L-shaped path horizontally from `p3.east` to a point 1.5cm up and to the right.  I put the red bullet there just to illustrate it; it's not necessary for your final diagram.  Then the path goes to a point 1cm to the right of `p2.south`.

[image: second code output]

You can fiddle with the positioning of that intermediate node any way you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I were to connnect box3 back to box2, I usually use squiggly line. But if I were to use straight lines, how do I do that. For example I want to go from box3.east to box2.south. I would do `-|` but I want to connect to right of box2.south. Can I go horizontal then vertical, then horizontal and then vertical again?

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Yes, you can do that if you put a coordinate in between.  But I'm not sure what you mean by "right of `box2.south`".  Is that the same as `box2.south east`?  Or do you mean a point between `box2.south` and `box2.south east`?

Comment: i meant 1cm right of the midpoint of box2.south

Comment: @arunmoezhi: see edit.  If you have questions about other techniques it's probably better to start a new question (the one you originally asked has been answered).