# How to create abstract factory pattern UML using pgf-umlcd?

Tags: pgf-umlcd

[image]

How to create `NYPizzaIngredientFactory` to `others` association using one command/ anything easy in `pgf-umlcd`?

[image]

Mainly, I want the `unidirectionalassociation` from one source to multiple targets.

I am trying this -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{class}{Factory}{0,0}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{ProductA}{4,5}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{ProductB}{-2,5}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{ProductC}{-8,5}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}
  \unidirectionalAssociation{Factory}{creates}{}{ProductA}
  \unidirectionalAssociation{Factory}{creates}{}{ProductB}
  \unidirectionalAssociation{Factory}{creates}{}{ProductC}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output -

[image]

But I don't want 3 incoming lines to `Factory` class.

Comment: Lots of similar questions have been asked before, if not in the specific case of `pgf-umlcd` (not that it matters much, it's all TikZ anyway). A couple of examples I found: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178603/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280521/ If you're unable to figure it out, add a complete code example to your question with what you've tried, and someone will surely be able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. probably I couldn't explain the asking? I can use `\unidirectionalassociation` to one source to one target. But here is one source to multiple target. I edited my question.

Comment: `\unidirectionalassociation` only draws a single straight line. That's it. You can still do what you ask for, but you'll need to use something else. But please post code, I don't feel like making up an example only to have to redo it three times afterwards because I didn't fully understand what you were after in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you can't really do that with `\unidirectionalassociation` the way it is defined. It might be possible to redefine, but I think drawing those arrows using TikZ-macros instead is just as well. There will be several ways of doing this, I'll explain one here.

In the code below, the first thing I do, after the classes, is

```
  \draw [umlcd style] (Factory.north) -- ++(0,2cm)
                      coordinate (tmp)
                      node[right,midway] {creates};
```

This draws a line using a style defined by `pgf-umlcd`, starting at the top of the `Factory` class, and ending 2cm higher. The `++` indicates that the coordinate, `(0,2cm)`, is relative to the previous coordinate. Then I define a coordinate at that endpoint called `tmp`, which is used later.

I also add a node (used to place text) halfway along the line (that's what `midway` means), on the `right` side of it. If you don't want the word `creates` next to this line, remove `node[right,midway] {creates}`. (But *don't* remove the semicolon, that is required to end the path.)

Then I draw three lines starting at the `tmp` coordinate defined above, to each of the product classes:

```
  \foreach \endpoint in {ProductA,ProductB,ProductC}
    \draw [umlcd style,fill=none,->] (tmp) -| (\endpoint.south)
                                     node[pos=0.75,right] {creates};
```

I used a loop here, you could also have three separate `\draw` statements. For these lines, I add `fill=none,->` in addition to `umlcd style`. The first is needed because the style sets a fill colour, so filling must be disabled. The latter is needed to activate the arrow tip at the end of the lines.

The syntax `(a) -| (b)` means that instead of drawing a straight line, TikZ draws first horizontally from the point `a`, and then vertically up to `b`.

Again I add a node, and again, remove it if you don't want it. The `pos=0.75` normally means that it should be placed at the point that is 75% of the way from a to b. For paths using `-|` (or `|-`) however, `pos=0.5` is always at the corner, so `pos=0.75` is halfway between the corner and the end of the path.

Output and complete code below.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{class}{Factory}{0,0}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{ProductA}{4,5}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{ProductB}{-2,5}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{ProductC}{-8,5}
    \attribute{}
    \attribute{}
    \operation{}
    \operation{}
  \end{class}

  \draw [umlcd style] (Factory.north) -- ++(0,2cm)
                      coordinate (tmp)
                      node[right,midway] {creates};

  \foreach \endpoint in {ProductA,ProductB,ProductC}
    \draw [umlcd style,fill=none,->] (tmp) -| (\endpoint.south)
                                     node[pos=0.75,right] {creates};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `standalone` package. Is there any benefit over `article` package I used?

Comment: How can I shift the first line`(Factory.north) -- ++(0,2cm)` 1cm left?

Comment: @alhelal The `standalone` class (not package) crops/extends the page size to the size of the content. Your diagram was far too wide for a standard `article`, that's the only reason I switched. Just try my example, and then replace `\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}` with `\documentclass{article}`. For the second: `([xshift=-1cm]Factory.north)`

Comment: Using aritcle class I expended many time to fit my contents. Thank you.

Comment: How can I set a caption to this UML diagram. i.e-`Abstract Factory Pattern`?

Comment: @alhelal `\begin{figure} \centering \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture} \caption{...} \end{figure}`?

Comment: that create two page unnecessarily and put the caption in top. see [this](https://imgur.com/a/Q9KYM) code here [code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25787087/)

Comment: @alhelal That's because of the `standalone` class, didn't think about that. Did you mean a numbered caption, or did you just want to add some text somewhere?

Comment: yes, I want to add this pdf inside another document, so I include the pattern name with the page.

Comment: @alhelal `\node [above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {Abstract ..};` to put some text at the top, replace `above` with `below` and `north` with `south` to put it at the bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67430/discussion-between-alhelal-and-torbjorn-t).